# how to connect to TFS by authentication (Team foundation server) in your asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I'm trying to create a page where I will be getting all the Workitem in the tfs. But I don't know how to Connect to TFS. what reference I need to add
currently my code is ( which I get from internet ).

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");  
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(credential);  

TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(  
new Uri("https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"),  
basicCred);  

tpc.Authenticate();
```

[image: code with error]
[image]

Comment: You might need to add Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common for this. 
Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: but it's not a console app

Comment: search `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` on the nuget and add it to the solution

Comment: it would be same. Check and let me know if you are not able to use it

Comment: added Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client

Comment: i am getting the error image added @G_S

Comment: I think this problem related to the package that you use. try my answer please and tell me the result.

Comment: @AkhilJain Please let me know if your problem has been solved.

Comment: will check tomorrow server down for 3 days

Comment: @AkhilJain Is your issue solved?

Comment: no answer provides deprecated class

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT could u help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022991/how-to-get-a-task-id-storyid-featureid-feature-name-by-wiql-in-c-sharp-by-1-qu

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add this library using nuget:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
```

Also you need this namespace, so you should add it to the page:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
```

Then you can connect to TFS with following code:

```
var collectionUri = new Uri("https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");

var credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: it's showing TfsTeamProjectCollection is depreciated

Comment: I can't understand what exactly happened, please give me more details about the problem.

Comment: image added in question only

Comment: have you added this library (via nuget) to your solution?: `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`

Comment: can you create a new project and do the things that I mentioned? I do the same and it works fine. I think it causes because of the other libraries that you may have.