# WIQL query to get all the team and the users in a Project?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem, wiql

let's say i have a project name ="Scrum" and that has some users the project and got sprints so **i want dstinct users of the Project that the Sprints in Scrum **. image attached.
[image]

Comment: Whats' the disinct, a spelling mistake?

Comment: Hi Akhil Jain, any update on this issue?

Comment: sir i don't know about API could u please update ur answer by c# code wiql @PatrickLu-MSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also this code for teams:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProcessConfiguration.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace QueryLinkedWIQL
{
    class Program
    {

        static List<TeamFoundationTeam> ListTeams(TfsTeamProjectCollection pTpc, Project pProject)
        {
            TfsTeamService _teamService = pTpc.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            var _teams = _teamService.QueryTeams(pProject.Uri.ToString());

            return (from t in _teams select t).ToList();
        }

        static bool GetTeamsSettings(TfsTeamProjectCollection pTpc, TeamFoundationTeam pTeam)
        {
            try
            {
                var _teamConfig = pTpc.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();

                var _configs = _teamConfig.GetTeamConfigurations(new Guid[] { pTeam.Identity.TeamFoundationId  });

                Console.WriteLine("============={0}==================", pTeam.Name);

                Console.WriteLine("Team Members: ");

                foreach (var _member in pTeam.GetMembers(pTpc, MembershipQuery.Expanded))
                    Console.WriteLine("Display Name: " + _member.DisplayName + " || Is active: " + _member.IsActive);

                foreach( var _config in _configs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Team current iteration: " + _config.TeamSettings.CurrentIterationPath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Team selected iterations:");
                    foreach (var _iteration in _config.TeamSettings.IterationPaths)
                        Console.WriteLine(_iteration);
                    Console.WriteLine("Team selected areas:");
                    foreach (var _area in _config.TeamSettings.TeamFieldValues)
                        Console.WriteLine("Area path: " + _area.Value + " || Include children: " + _area.IncludeChildren.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("===============================");


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string _teamProject = "YourProjectName";

            try
            {
                TfsTeamProjectCollection _tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://yourserver/DefaultCollection"));

                WorkItemStore _wistore = _tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

                var _teams = ListTeams(_tpc, _wistore.Projects[_teamProject]);
                foreach (var _team in _teams) GetTeamsSettings(_tpc, _team);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to get all the iteration(sprints) and Distinct user in a PROJECT (forget abt the team) could u modify ur answer.

Comment: hey @Shamray could u help me with my Question on WIQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434095/how-to-get-all-the-users-along-with-team-iteration-of-a-project-of-tfs-wiql

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you want to get all teams (include all users in the team) and corresponding sprint for each team.

It's not able to do this through WIQL. **[WIQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306(v=vs.120).aspx)** is a work item query language which used to query for bugs, tasks, other types of work items. The return value should be work item.

Instead, you could use **Rest API** to achieve your requirement.

1.First, [Get a list of teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-list-of-teams) in a project.

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1/teams?api-version=2.2
```

2.[Get a team's members](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-teams-members)

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1/teams/564e8204-a90b-4432-883b-d4363c6125ca/members/?api-version=2.2
```

3.[Get a team's iterations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/iterations)

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/TeamSettings/Iterations?[$timeframe=current&]api-version={version}
```

Combine with the above Rest APIs, you could be able to achieve this get teams name with there Sprints in Scrum project and all  users of the team.

Comment: any way to get all the Iteration's of a project ?