# how to get all the Users along with Team Iteration of a project of TFS WIQL?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

i want to get all the users with there Iteration in a project.
Lets say Project 'Precient' has 9 distinct users with 20 iteration so i want distinct users with all the Iteration in the project `WIQL C#`.it's related to the Question.
[WIQL query to get all the team and the users in a Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092830/wiql-query-to-get-all-the-team-and-the-users-in-a-project)

but does not help me fully

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and explain exactly what didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get that through REST API or Net API. This is sample for Net API.

1. You may get all users from group "Project Valid Users"
2. You may get all Iterations from Project root Iterations.

   ```
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace GetUserіAndItearions
   {
       class Program
       {
           public class Iteration
           {
               public string Path;
               public DateTime DateFrom;
               public DateTime DateTo;
           }

           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               string _teamProject = "Your_Project_Name";

               try
               {
                   TfsTeamProjectCollection _tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://your_server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));

                   GetAllUsers(_tpc, _teamProject);
                   GetAllIterations(_tpc, _teamProject);

               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                   Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
               }
           }

           private static void GetAllIterations(TfsTeamProjectCollection pTpc, string pProjectName)
           {
               List<Iteration> _its = new List<Iteration>();
               WorkItemStore _wistore = pTpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

               var _css = pTpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();


               foreach (Node _node in _wistore.Projects[pProjectName].IterationRootNodes)
                   FillIterations(_css, _node, _its);


               Console.WriteLine("Iterations:");
               foreach (Iteration _it in _its) Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}-{2}", _it.Path, 
                   (_it.DateFrom == DateTime.MinValue) ? "0" : _it.DateFrom.ToShortDateString(), (_it.DateTo== DateTime.MinValue) ? "0" : _it.DateTo.ToShortDateString());
           }

           private static void FillIterations(ICommonStructureService4 pCss, Node pNode, List<Iteration> pIts)
           {
               var _nodeInfo = pCss.GetNode(pNode.Uri.AbsoluteUri);

               pIts.Add(new Iteration { Path = _nodeInfo.Path,
                   DateFrom = (_nodeInfo.StartDate == null) ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)_nodeInfo.StartDate,
                   DateTo = (_nodeInfo.FinishDate == null) ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)_nodeInfo.FinishDate });

               if (pNode.HasChildNodes)
                   foreach (Node _node in pNode.ChildNodes)
                       FillIterations(pCss, _node, pIts);
           }

           private static void GetAllUsers(TfsTeamProjectCollection pTpc, string pProjectName)
           {
               List<string> listUsers = new List<string>();

               WorkItemStore _wistore = pTpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
               var _gss = pTpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

               var _teamProject = _wistore.Projects[pProjectName];
               string _validGroupName = "[" + pProjectName + "]\\Project Valid Users";

               TeamFoundationIdentity _group = _gss.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName, _validGroupName, MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);

               List<string> _memebersIds = new List<string>();
               foreach (var _member in _group.Members) _memebersIds.Add(_member.Identifier);

               var _members = _gss.ReadIdentities(IdentitySearchFactor.Identifier, _memebersIds.ToArray(), MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);

               foreach (var _member in _members) if (!_member[0].IsContainer) listUsers.Add(_member[0].DisplayName);

               Console.WriteLine("Users:");
               foreach (var _user in listUsers) Console.WriteLine("{0}", _user);
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: need ur help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025525/how-to-find-the-field-detail-of-a-product-backlog-item-tfs-by-wiql

Answer (score 1):

It's not able to get users from Team via WIQL. WIQL is a work item query language which used to query for bugs, tasks, other types of work items. The return value should be work item.

You need use api as @Shamray provided to retrieve the users. The following blog also provided an example:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2012/05/20/tfs-api-part-44-vs11-teams-and-team-members/

Comment: is there any way i can use rest api without PAT (token)?

Comment: i am using TFS 2015 !! pls write C# code to connect TFS by REST api and get all users and iteration of a project

Comment: You could use **Basic** Authentication with your windows credential in your api. The rest api you should refer to [Get a list of teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-list-of-teams), [Get a team's members](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/teams#get-a-teams-members), [Get a team's iterations](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/iterations). Regarding how to use a REST api in C# code, please refer to this website: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=vsts