# how to get Task id,Feature id,Complete hrs by WIQL tfs by date?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

how to get Task,Feature id,completed hours by date.
lets say there is a 
task 123 in which was created on a sprint which start date is 1st July and end at 10th July

task 123 effort hours is 5 completed hrs is 0 from 1-7-2018   
and on 5th July effort is 3 hrs completed 2 hrs 
and on 10th July effort is 1 hr and completed is 4 hrs

so how can i find task id,Feature id (by Tree WIQL) of date from 1st July to 5th July.

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: already did in Question

Comment: @D-Shih what more did u Require here

Comment: you can not get history details with wiql. You may use rest api for revision as @Andy Li-MSFT  said. But for tfs also you may to connect to Warehouse database and select that information from history table: [Work Item History tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sql-reports/work-item-history-tables?view=tfs-2018)

Comment: by andy advise what if i created a task on 10.7.2018 and on 11.7.2018 i changed the Priorty or any ther field beside hours then Changed date of that task will be today @ShamraiAleksander

Comment: what tool (VS) or language (c#) do you use? I'm trying to create test solution.

Comment: VS 2017 C# @ShamraiAleksander

Comment: @Shrey Have you resolved the issue by below answers? any update?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT no sir i still need SQL Query for VS 2017 for this as i am not getting desired Result by WIQL and API

Comment: @Shrey Based on my investigation we can not find the specific record in DB, So I don't think you can completely achieve that, the solutions we mentioned in below answers should be the closest solutions on this issue....

Comment: can't achieve that in DB also ? but @ShamraiAleksander said we can !!

Comment: @Shrey Yeah, Theoretically Ok, but actually based on my checking, I cannot find the relation chains... in my opinion it's not worth spending too much time on the issue... just my suggestion...

Comment: can u provide me the table/Query which i can check in VS 2017 TFS DB ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, seems you want to get the history (revisions) for a specific work item.

If it is, then you can use the REST API to retrieve that: See [Get a list of work items revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/wit/revisions?view=tfs-2018#get-a-list-of-work-items-revisions)

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}/revisions?api-version={version}[&$top={int}&$skip={int}&$expand={enum{relations}
```

Try below sample to filter the list by date:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://172.17.16.115:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$witid = "12",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$witid/revisions?"+"$"+"expand=all"          
$response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value

# Filter the revisions changed between the date '2018-07-01'and '2018-07-05' and remaining work >=O
$revisions = $response | where({$_.fields.'System.ChangedDate' -ge '2018-07-01' -and $_.fields.'System.ChangedDate' -le '2018-07-06' -and $_.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork' -ge '0' } )

$witrevisions = @()

foreach($revision in $revisions){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WorkItemType" = $revision.fields.'System.WorkItemType'         
          "WorkItemID" = $revision.fields.'System.Id'
          "Revid" = $revision.rev
          "RemainingWork" = $revision.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork'
          "Relations" = $revision.relations.url
          "ChangeddDate" = $revision.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
        } 

    $witrevisions += $customObject      
}

$witrevisions | Select-Object `
                WorkItemID,
                WorkItemType,
                Revid,
                RemainingWork, 
                Relations,
                ChangeddDate #| export-csv -Path E:\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: but what if only priorty or any other field changes of the Task changes not the time hrs (completed ,remaining, effort hours) @andy

Comment: @Shrey We can not exactly achieve your requirements which only filter out the completed ,remaining hours changed date as this isn't such a field/element for tracking it. So we can only narrow down by the changed date, then you can filter the completed ,remaining, effort hours from the response. See the updated  script...

Comment: could u pls tell me how to do it by .net code+WIQL rather than API

Comment: @Shrey If you mean to get the revisions for a specific work item which equals to the solution in above answer, then WIQL is not available for that, WIQL is for filtering work items from workitem store. See [Syntax for the Work Item Query Language (WIQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/wiql-syntax?view=vsts). To get the revisions by .net code, you can reference this article: [TFS API : TFS Work Item All Changes History](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117462/TFS-API-TFS-Work-Item-All-Changes-History)

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT what if i created a task on 10.7.2018 and on 11.7.2018 i changed the Priorty or any ther field beside hours then Changed date of that task will be today

Comment: @AkhilJain Yeah, So I said we can not exactly achieve the requirements, the workaround can narrow down the scope, then you can filter the ones which related to completed ,remaining from the response.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT can we achieve if we have TFS DB access ?

Comment: @AkhilJain Theoretically Ok, but actually No, unless you can find the specific tag/field which record the hours changed (completed ,remaining, effort hours). Based on my investigation cannot find a specific column/table which record the hours changed in DB.  Actually the REST API is also try retrieving data from the DB

Answer (score 1):

I have created test solution. It based on rest api. It requires nugate packages:

- [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)
- [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient/)

And you have to update them after install because I had the error: [Inheritance security rules violated by type](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100)

Test source code:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;

namespace GetFTTaskCompleteForDates
{
    class Program
    {
        public class FTTaskComleted
        {
            public int FTID = 0;
            public int TaskID = 0;
            public int CompletedOnDate = 0;
            public int CompletedFieldValue = 0;
            public DateTime ReportDT;
        }

        static public class WIQLS
        {
            static public string ChangedTasksFromDate = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{0}'  AND  [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'  AND  [System.ChangedDate] >= '{1}-{2}-{3}T00:00:00.0000000' ORDER BY [System.Id]";
            static public string GetTopParentFeature = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = '{0}'  AND  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature') And ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And ([Target].[System.Id] = {1}) ORDER BY [System.Id] mode(Recursive,ReturnMatchingChildren)";
        }

        static string ServiceUrl = "http://tfs-srv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
        static string TeamProject = "VSTSAgile";
        static WorkItemTrackingHttpClient WiClient = null; 
        static VssConnection ServiceConnection = null;
        static string CompletedWorkFieldRef = "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork";
        static string ChangedDateFieldRef = "System.ChangedDate";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime _startDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 19);
            DateTime _finishDate = DateTime.Today;  // set to DateTime.MinValue if only one date
            //DateTime _finishDate = DateTime.MinValue;

            List<FTTaskComleted> _lstReport = new List<FTTaskComleted>();

            if (!ConnectToService()) return;

            Dictionary<int, int> _dctTasksFeatures = GetTaskAndFeatures(_startDate);

            if (_dctTasksFeatures.Keys.Count > 0) FillReportList(_dctTasksFeatures, _lstReport, _startDate, _finishDate);

            foreach (FTTaskComleted _item in _lstReport)
                Console.WriteLine("DATE:{0} -- FT:{1} -- TSK:{2} -- HRS -- {3}", _item.ReportDT.ToShortDateString(), _item.FTID, _item.TaskID, _item.CompletedOnDate);
        }

        //Fill list with hours for each date and task
        private static void FillReportList(Dictionary<int, int> pDctTasksFT, List<FTTaskComleted> pLstReport, DateTime pStartDate, DateTime pFinishtDate)
        {

            foreach (int _taskId in pDctTasksFT.Keys)
            {
                List<WorkItem> _revs = WiClient.GetRevisionsAsync(_taskId).Result;

                DateTime _lastDate = DateTime.MinValue; //last processed date for revisions of work item
                int _lastHours = int.MinValue; //last processed value of compteted work for revisions of work item

                foreach (WorkItem _rev in _revs)
                {                    
                    if (!_rev.Fields.Keys.Contains(CompletedWorkFieldRef) || !_rev.Fields.Keys.Contains(ChangedDateFieldRef)) continue;
                    DateTime _changedDate;
                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(_rev.Fields[ChangedDateFieldRef].ToString(), out _changedDate)) continue;

                    bool _inscope = false;

                    // calculate hours based on previous revision
                    int _completedValue, _completedDiff;
                    if (!int.TryParse(_rev.Fields[CompletedWorkFieldRef].ToString(), out _completedValue)) continue;

                    if (_lastHours == int.MinValue) _completedDiff = _completedValue;
                    else _completedDiff = _completedValue - _lastHours;

                    _lastHours = _completedValue;

                    // check for date of revision between needed dates
                    if (pFinishtDate == DateTime.MinValue) { if (_changedDate.Date == pStartDate.Date) _inscope = true; }
                    else if (_changedDate.Date >= pStartDate.Date && _changedDate.Date <= pFinishtDate.Date) _inscope = true;

                    if (_inscope && _completedDiff != 0)
                    {
                        if (_lastDate.Date == _changedDate.Date && pLstReport.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //update existing item if several changes in one day
                            pLstReport[pLstReport.Count - 1].CompletedOnDate += _completedDiff;
                            pLstReport[pLstReport.Count - 1].CompletedFieldValue = _completedValue;
                        }
                        else // add new report item
                            pLstReport.Add(
                                new FTTaskComleted
                                {
                                    FTID = pDctTasksFT[_taskId],
                                    TaskID = _taskId, ReportDT = _changedDate,
                                    CompletedOnDate = _completedDiff,
                                    CompletedFieldValue = _completedValue }
                                );

                        _lastDate = _changedDate;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        static Dictionary<int, int> GetTaskAndFeatures(DateTime pStartDate)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> _taskft = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            List<int> _ids = GetTasksIdsForPeriod(pStartDate);

            if (_ids.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(int _wiId in _ids)
                    if (!AddFeaturesToTask(_wiId, _taskft)) break;
            }

            return _taskft;
        }

        //add top level parent to task id and exclude tasks without parent features
        static bool AddFeaturesToTask(int pId, Dictionary<int, int> pWiDict)
        {
            try
            {
                Wiql _wiql = new Wiql();
                _wiql.Query = String.Format(WIQLS.GetTopParentFeature, TeamProject, pId);

                WorkItemQueryResult _res = WiClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(_wiql).Result;

                if (_res.WorkItemRelations.Count() > 1)
                    pWiDict.Add(pId, _res.WorkItemRelations.ElementAt(0).Target.Id); //first is a top parent
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Query problem:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        //Connect to tfs/vsts
        static public bool ConnectToService()
        {
            try
            {
                VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
                creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

                ServiceConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(ServiceUrl), creds);
                ServiceConnection.ConnectAsync().Wait();
                WiClient = ServiceConnection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection problem:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        //find all tasks changed after start date. beacouse we can not select revisions between dates.
        static public List<int> GetTasksIdsForPeriod(DateTime pStart)
        {
            List<int> _ids = new List<int>();

            try
            {
                Wiql _wiql = new Wiql();
                _wiql.Query = String.Format(WIQLS.ChangedTasksFromDate, TeamProject, pStart.Year, pStart.Month, pStart.Day);

                WorkItemQueryResult _res = WiClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(_wiql).Result;

                if (_res.WorkItems.Count() > 0)
                    foreach (WorkItemReference _wi in _res.WorkItems) _ids.Add(_wi.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Query problem:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return _ids;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pls explain what it does !! (some snapshot from VS) pls

Comment: /find all tasks changed after start date. beacouse we can not select revisions beetwen dates. what does that mean ?

Comment: there is no wiql to get revisions, so we can not get work item that was changed between two dates. Solution steps: 1. Get all tasks that was changed after start date for report period (GetTasksIdsForPeriod). 2. Get parent features for these tasks (AddFeaturesToTask). 3. For each task get all revisions and: 1) calculate complete hours difference for each revision 2) include to the report changes (revisions) between start and finish date. (FillReportList)

Comment: is this Possible(get the hrs between dates) if i can access of the DB tables ?

Comment: Yes. You can find an example in the [Reporting Guide](https://vsardata.blob.core.windows.net/projects/TFS%20Practical%20Reporting%20Guide%20-%20Data%20Warehouse.pdf) in the Time Tracking Report section

Comment: pls help i have asked the Question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398097/how-to-get-task-id-feature-id-complete-hrs-by-accessing-tfs-warehouse-by-date-in

Comment: @Shamri could u pls tell me the Tables which i could use in VS 2017 ?