# how to get Task id,Feature id,Complete hrs by accessing TFS Warehouse by date in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tfs, data-warehouse, tfs-workitem

how to get Task,Feature id,completed hours by date `SQL SERVER QUERY`.
lets say there is a 
task 123 in which was created on a sprint which start date is 1st July(1.1.2018) and end at 10th July(10.7.2018)

```
task 123 effort hours is 5 hrs. completed hrs is 0 and renaming hours is 5 hrs on 1-7-2018   <br/>
and on 5th July effort is 5 hrs completed 2 hrs and Renaming hours is 3 hrs <br/>
and on 10th July effort is 5 hr and completed is 4 hrs and Remaining hours us 1 hr <br/>
```

so how can i find task id,Feature id (by Flat Structure) of date from 1st July to 5th July.

- which table to access In the DB ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the work items that changed from a range of date?

Comment: change or not change i want there hours that's it along with other details

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we don't recommend query database directly, you could run TFS query or use [TFS api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the information you want:

[image]

Or you could try the extension mentioned in [this UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2060101-tfs-needs-the-ability-to-track-hours-tied-to-a-wor).

Comment: changed date wil not solve it let's say i have changed only priorty not the hours then what ?

Comment: If this is the case, you could use REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the work items that changed date from 7/1~7/5, and then filter whether `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork` field changed.

Comment: BUT HOW TO check old value with new value?

Comment: The api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) could return all revisions of the work items, so you could check all revisions of the `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork` field.

Comment: @Shrey Same question with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239131/how-to-get-task-id-feature-id-complete-hrs-by-wiql-tfs-by-date